# how to reconstruct in 3d of a scene from two images

Tags: python, opencv, 3d, stereo-3d, structure-from-motion

I wish to make a 3D reconstruction of a scene. For that, I have 2 images of the scene taken from two different angles.
Is there a library that does that? (I work in python)
if not, what are the steps that must be followed?
if you have the code ready, it is welcome.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it for myself yet, but it seems simple with OpenCV.

OpenCV has [module for 3D reconstruction](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).

Also check out this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_depthmap/py_depthmap.html).

**Upd.** Please look at comments from @berak below. I misunderstood yours question at first.

I found [SfM-Toy-Library](https://github.com/royshil/SfM-Toy-Library) library on github, which uses algorithms from mentioned "Multiple View Geometry" book. It's written using OpenCV and better relates to the topic, but it might be not so easy to use library in Python.

Comment: ^^ that refers to *calibrated* stereo-cams, not the setup above.

Comment: @berak My mistake, thank you. I'll delete this answer in a few minutes.

Comment: probably @lyn87 should re-think his approach, the calibrated way your topics above describe, is the far easier one !

Comment: i saw this tuto, my question is : what is the relation between the calibration and calculation of disparity map ?

Comment: @lyn87 you will need calibrated stereo cameras to calculate a disparity map. from there' it's easy to get 3d coords.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vtk 
First step is image processing and second step is 3d reconstructions
For example you can try for first step:

1)Median Filtering

2)Image contrast

3)Thresholding

4)Noise reduction

And second step includes:

1)vtkMarchingCubes

2)vtkPolyDataMapper

3)vtkActor

4)Renderer

Also you can read this article : [enter link description here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2df6/631ed8cac0487f029f64b21e7e930ed97cf1.pdf)